# knockout using visible with truthy/falsey condition

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to use `knockout 2.2` to do a simple `data-bind="visible..."` on a `div`.

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">this is visible</div>
<div data-bind="visible: $('#test').is(':visible')">show if test is visible</div>
```

As-is, "test" is set to `display:none` but the second div is still showing up. Why? Can this be done? Note: I have all the script ref's included, to `jQuery` and `knockout 2.2`.

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/uviwiz/1/edit

Note: I'm not doing a `ko.applyBindings` call or anything like that. Maybe I need to after declaring an observable function?

Comment: You have to call applyBindings, or else knockout won't run.

Comment: Also, $("#test").is(":visible") is not a ko.observable so it won't toggle dynamically when the 'test' div is shown/hidden. It will only work on the first load of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There no dependency between the first and the second div.
So if the first div changes it doesn't apply its change to the second one.

You could try this :

```
var ViewModel = function()
{
  var self = this;

  self.boolean =  ko.observable(true);

};
var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);



setTimeout(function(){
  vm.boolean(false);
}, 2000);


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test" data-bind="visible:boolean">this is visible</div>
  <div data-bind="visible:boolean">only show if above div is visible or not</div>
  <div id="debug"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how could I make the self.boolean take in an argument? so I could do `data-bind="visible: boolean(3)"`, with `ko.computable(function(val) { return val===3; })` (would be true for whenever u pass in 3, false otherwise)

Comment: ok, here's the question. why can't I change it? I've changed the boolean function to be whether or not a particular `div` is visible or not. http://jsfiddle.net/damienobringer/WKEen/

Comment: You can't change it, because boolean is a function, so can't set it. In this code boolean is used as getter.
May be you could give us more explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: trying to make this example work: http://jsfiddle.net/WKEen/4/  where if you click the "toggle" button, the visible's are updated. not sure if it can be done :/